# Would a being with electrical powers be able to stick to things using electricity in some way?

Tags: science-based, super-powers, electricity

I have a character that can produce electricity. Would he be able to stick to things and move around on walls and ceilings using his electricity power in some way? It would need to be able to support a person. Would static electricity be able to support a person? If so, what would the limits of it be? If possible I want something that could work on any surface.

Comment: Rubber shoes/gloves will help so you don't dissipate your charge as soon as you touch whatever it is.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the limit of this power on your own: by taking off a synthetic or woolen sweater, for example, or by peeling a plastic wrap from a container.

Your body will be charged with static electricity and you will start attracting some things to you. I.e. the plastic foil you peeled won't leave your hands when you try to throw it in the garbage bin, but will stick there. Or you might notice a little spark when you try to insert the key in the door in a dark room.

The two examples above predate from my own experience, and also give some insight on the limitation of such power:

- you will attract only dielectric materials, any grounded conductive material will dissipate your static charge to ground
- your power will strongly be limited by humid atmosphere. So no missions in St. Louis for Static Man!

On top of those, you will face a safety hazard: to attract heavy objects you will need to induce a strong charge, but you will need to be properly insulated from the surrounding, to avoid zapping yourself or others in the process.

Comment: Yeah there's a fine line between strong static charge and low end lightning.

Answer (score 2):

**Electromagnetism**

By circulating a large electrical current in his hands and feet, he can turn them into electromagnets allowing him to cling to steel structures.

By turning the ability on and off he can effectively climb skyscrapers

Answer (score 0):

By ionizing the air between two electrodes, he can create an air stream. A strong enough jet stream could make him fly. An ion drive airplane is workable, though still in its infacy.
https://youtu.be/boB6qu5dcCw

The lack of wings means the drive should be as powerful as that of a jet engine, but that doesn't mean it's impossible.